# How to convert between different pylab.histogram results

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

what is the formula relating variables `values1` and `values2` in the following code:

```
values1, _ = pylab.histogram(data, bins, density = False)

values2, _ = pylab.histogram(data, bins, density = True)
```

?

Or put in another way, given `values1` how can I get `values2` thus avoiding another call to `pylab.histogram` ?

Thanks

Comment: To avoid confusion, note that `pylab.histogram` is actually the `numpy` histogram function, not `matplotlib`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The one-dimensional density is defined as the `values / length`. But it's also a normalization method for histograms.

So in order to get from your original values to the `density`-values just divide by the total count (normalization) and the bin-width (density):

```
bin_width = bins[1:] - bins[:-1]
values2 = values1 / np.sum(values1) / bin_width
```

A quick test with a random array:

```
from matplotlib import pylab
import numpy as np
data = np.random.randint(0,10, 1000)
bins = np.array([0,1,2,5,11])
values1, _ = pylab.histogram(data, bins, density = False)
print(values1) 
# [ 97, 117, 278, 508]
values2, _ = pylab.histogram(data, bins, density = True)
print(values2) 
# [ 0.097, 0.117, 0.09266667, 0.08466667]
bin_width = bins[1:] - bins[:-1]
print(values1 / np.sum(values1) / bin_width) 
# [ 0.097, 0.117, 0.09266667, 0.08466667]
```

So it is the same for this case.

Comment: I suppose you tested in Python 3.x ... I am in Python 2.7.11 and had to do this on the last line of code: `print values1 / (1.0 * np.sum(values1)) / bin_width`

Comment: @mljrg -Yes I'm using python3. You haven't tagged it `python 2.x` so I assumed a solution for any python version would be ok. You could also use `from __future__ import division, print_function`  to bypass the difference in behaviour. :)